# Infinite Redirect Loop with PURL and spaces_og

Tags: organic-groups, features, 7

I created a calendar feature for organic groups, and tried to enable it in a group with spaces_og.  The page refreshes saying changes have been saved but the feature is still disabled.  In the logs, there is a message that purl prevented a redirect loop.

I realize spaces is still in dev with d7.  Is this a known issue?  Did I do something wrong when creating my feature, or is there a better way to create features for use in organic groups?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred because I didn't have a path prefix set for purl.  I created the group prior to enabling purl and spaces.  After adding the path in the group node edit form, the redirect loop was no longer present.